# What's the use of loadBtyes() in FileReference Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I require a functionality making use of FileReference Class in AS3.0 . However I don't understand one part where it requires the use of ByteArray. To my understanding, FileReference only needs the selected file, and it SHOULD store the data automatically. But as per the following process, a 2nd step is again required, where fileReference data is assigned to a variable of type ByteArray, and is loaded again. What is this 2nd step required for. Why the data is not stored in a single step ??

```
private function fileReference_SELECT(e:Event):void
        {
            fileRef_Fr.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileRef_Fr_SELECT);
            fileRef_Fr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileReference_COMPLETE);
            fileRef_Fr.load();

        }   


  private function fileReference_COMPLETE(e:Event):void
            {
                fileRef_Fr.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileRef_Fr_load_COMPLETE);
                var rawBytes:ByteArray = fileRef_Fr.data;
                loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
                loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, contentLoaderInfo_COMPLETE)
                loader.loadBytes(rawBytes);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step loads just the raw bytes from the file into memory. The second step reads/parses/converts those bytes into a `Bitmap`, `Sound`, `MovieClip` or whatever is contained in the file.

Comment: But, why FileReference class doesnot do it automatically ? Is their any place, where the 2nd step may not be required ? ( as i think, the 2nd step is always important ).

Comment: actually, there is something strange in this code. FileReference does it automatically, as shown in the line `var rawBytes:ByteArray = fileRef_Fr.data;`. After this, it looks more like the leftover of a `URLLoader` usage. I don't think it should be there.